# Emacs: what is the most efficient way to remove the quote?

Tags: macos, emacs

This is the text I am working on:

```
is_check_point(9) ->
    {yes, ['{0,20}', '{3,23}', '{6,26}', '{27,47}', '{30,50}', '{33,53}', '{54,74}', '{57,77}']}
```

I have text like the above repeated for many time. They appear in a file which has single quotes all over the place.

I would like to remove the single quote that surrounded the tuple (the language is erlang).

I am using Aquamacs on OSX

Comment: It sounds like a job for `M-x query-replace` or `M-x replace-string`.

Comment: @lawlist how to repeat it multiple times? Some sort of macro? Will regex be easier?

Comment: `replace-string` will handle from the location of the cursor to the end of the buffer.  If you want the start of the buffer, then just goto the beginning of the buffer and perform your `replace-string`.  If you want to confirm each one, then use `query-replace`.  Unless you are doing a lot of this exact same stuff, you probably don't need a function specifically for that.  Here is an example of `(replace-regexp "'\{" "{" nil (point-min) (point-max))`, which you can evaluate with `M-x eval-expression`

Comment: @lawlist the replace-regexp sounds like a good idea. Can you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(defun anthony-kong ()
"Usage:  `M-x anthony-kong`"
(interactive)
  (replace-regexp "'\{" "{" nil (point-min) (point-max))
  (replace-regexp "'\}" "}" nil (point-min) (point-max)) )
```

Comment: A personalised function :-) Thanks very much!